# Cleaning office add-in cache

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, office-addins

I have taken over a previously written office add-in with yeoman. I have been changing settings and else but after the initial install to see how far it has gone I believe my outlook client has stored some kind of cache. When I try to install the updated version it still holds the logos and settings for the previous version but when install it on a system which did not have a previous version of it its all good.

Any suggestions help. I have tried deleting my local profile file and recreate it by relaunching outlook but that does not seem to have effect on the whole process.

Thanks

EDIT:

I am talking about the Outlook standalone client.

Comment: Try the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57909922/office-js-addin-with-excel-and-edge-webview-how-to-delete-cache/58553187#58553187

Answer (score 8):

*Outlook Desktop for Windows* add-in runs in iFrame of IE Web browser control. To clean up the cache of the add-in open IE browser, go to settings and remove cache. Re-launch your add-in and it should be as good as new.

*Outlook for web* user may run under supported browsers. In this case go to settings of the web browser used and remove the cache of this browser.

*Outlook Desktop for Mac* add-in runs under some kind of variation of web browser control (built in with Office 2016 for Mac) and how to remove cache over here is still puzzle for me.

If your application uses [RoamingSettings](https://dev.outlook.com/reference/add-ins/RoamingSettings.html) object, take a look if you saveAsync any custom properties and remove them as you need with following saveAsync.

EDIT:

Of cause the described methods above are for your/QA/dev use only. For your customers you, as developer, has to take care of the cache for the files you have changed, when posting new release. As your add-in is nothing else as website, use web technology to re-fresh cache of the browser. There are many ways to achieve that. For example you may change location of the files for new release ...

```
<script src="/v1.0/Commands.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/v1.1/Commands.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

or add some random parameter to the sources file ...

```
<script src="Commands.js?version=a56b34a87" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and so on. Those simple methods will force browser to reload the file content.

Comment: Thanks Slava, I realised I had not asked the question with full details. My mistake. I was talking about the standalone Outlook client.

Comment: standalone Outlook on Windows? In this case just remove IE cache, if your add-in doesn't use RoamingSettings..

Comment: Yes it is in Windows. That sounds alright, but what happens with customers that had already the add-in and install the new or the updates? I cannot expect everyone to have technical skills in order to clear their IE cache. (It was used previously within the company but now the company wants to release it for public use)

Comment: I have modified the answer. Please have a look.

Comment: The edit solves my javascript sources, but for example - some of the files being hosted, such as the logo in the task pane bar, got corrupted so they were just outputting the default blue icon for office store add-ins. We fixed those (republished them) and they were displaying properly on machines with new installation, but in cases like mine on my machine they were still with the default blue icon (all links were updated to be sure), so this is where I am wondering whether those paths and values (logos) are probably stored in some sort of cache.

Comment: It will be refreshed after some time, not right away. If you want to see the change immediately, change image path and/or image name. stackoverflow is QandA website, not the forum. If you think you've got your answer for original question, please mark it, it will help others to find it. If you have more questions please post another one. Best regards.

Comment: @IvNen, to force Outlook to refresh the icon, you can delete the cache folder `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Wef` (check out this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/52100396/968003)

Answer (score 1):

Press <kbd>Window</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> and paste following command

```
%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Wef\
```

***Note:*** Before deleting all files, please close Office 365 apps such as Outlook, etc. and then delete.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to give you my experience to complete previous answers:

I am developping a web add-in for Outlook 2013 with Angular 6 and with an authentication process using OAuth (going through OneLogin). I was able to authenticate and see the main view of my add-in in Outlook Web App (Chrome or IE as I sometimes have to debug on these two). Things happened differently in the desktop version, sadly. In Outlook 2013, I could only give my credentials once, access to my main view, but once I closed the task pane and I wanted to relaunch the add-in, I was blocked on the loading.

I figured it was probably a problem with Outlook 2013 cache, and maxpaj's answer did the trick ! I added the cache control headers to my index.html file and problem solved :) So thank you maxpaj for saving my time !

Comment: That sounds good. I currently am in a process of writing an office add-in with OAuth 2.0 verification (well paused right now as I have other work that needs doing first), but your comment gave me an idea as to improve our service. Thanks. I guess its a mutual help answer.