# Office Web Add-ins cache old js code

Tags: javascript, .net, caching, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

I am building a WEB office add-in but sometimes for some reasons when I change the js file of a page it's not reflected when I deploy in browser. It shows the old js code. Is it some caching by the Outlook WEB add-in? I recompile the solution, clear the browser cache, even logout/login to the Office account and the code is still the old one. I also delete the Add-in from the account, but nothing happens. Why is that?

Comment: Is this would help? ... [Cleaning office add-in cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43586353/cleaning-office-add-in-cache/43589705#43589705)

Comment: Slava's link should cover most of the bases. Make sure you clear your internet cache, in IE and you can also set IE to Check for Newer versions of stored pages "Every time I visit the WebPage) in Tools -> Options -> General -> Browsing History -> Settings. You should also make sure your web files are actually updating. It kind of seems like the webserver you are using is not updating the files. Try going to your webpage directly from another browser, or even another machine, and see if it has changed. If it has not, then it's likely a problem with whatever is hosting your files.