# Clear cache of Outlook WebAddin

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

Because of a directive in nginx, webaddin cached initial endpoint HTML page. Because of this, outlook fails to update new changes.

Even i restart plugin, request is not reaching server. How can i delete outlook cache to fetch latest page from server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right-click and reload the view. It will fetch the latest html from server endpoint.

Comment: If the page is still cached, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43589705/7823505).