# Icons for Outlook addin not updating

Tags: office365, office-js, outlook-web-addins

I have an icon for a button in my Outlook add-in.

For example, https:/xyz.com/img1 pointing to img1

Now if I update the image after deploying the add-in, the updated image is not loaded in the ribbon.

after update: https:/xyz.com/img1 pointing to img2.

Ideally, img2 should be visible in the ribbon, right?

Is there any cache that needs to be deleted? I have tried restarting Outlook client and desktop, but no change.

If I enable the add-in to a new user now, the new image is displayed as an icon, but for older users(for whom the add-in is enabled before changing the icon) the icon is still the old one.

How can we update the new icon in such scenarios?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

UPDATE:
There is now a whole article about [clearing the cache](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/dev/add-ins/testing/clear-cache).

ORIGINAL ANSWER:
Deleting the cache can often fix this issue. The cache location varies depending on the platform.

**For Windows:**
Delete the content of the folder %LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Wef.

**For Mac:**
Delete the content of the folder /Users/{your_name_on_the_device}/Library/Containers/com.Microsoft.OsfWebHost/Data/.

Comment: Rick is correct, clearing the cache on that users machine will force Outlook to update the icons. Specifically %LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Wef\Resources (though clearing out the whole Wef directory should be ok). Currently if you want to force an icon update, you need to change the path in your manifest. (i.e. in your example change https://example.com/img1 to https://example.com/img2)

Comment: @RickKirkham that folder on macOS doesn't exist in the case of Excel -- did the directory change or where would it be for Excel?

Comment: @FelixZumstein, See the update to my answer. I believe it has the info that you need.