# Office add-in caching data

Tags: office-js, office-addins

I have created an add-in, which loads some dynamic data when loaded. It works well in outlook web, but unfortunately has issues with the outlook desktop client(windows). The desktop client is caching data, hence the new and updated content is not being shown when the add-in when loaded.

I have also tried adding the "no-cache" meta tags.

Is there a rule/permission/key I can set in the manifest which restricts caching?

Comment: What do you mean by data? Are you referring to the JS that you're putting on your page (or css?)

Comment: Is this gonna be helpful ... [Cleaning office add-in cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43586353/cleaning-office-add-in-cache/43589705#43589705)? By the way, there is nothing in the manifest which force your web application do not cache.

Comment: Seems like you want to add some tags to the web page that is loaded for the addin. What you set for the webpage is entirely upto you and Outlook does not interfere with that. Check to see if your webpage works as expected on all browsers outside of the addin window too. Outlook desktop loads either the default browser or IE instance for the addin web page.

Comment: @MaviDomates I am calling an API and rendering its results in html.

Comment: So you're referring to the async data being cached? Have you setup the server in a way that the response is not cached?